# simultaneous pause javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to pause **but still run other code at the same time**.
For example:

```
while (true) {
    unit++
    // wait 3 seconds
}
// do this at the same time
while (true) {
    something += 25
    // wait 5 seconds
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is ran sequentially, so that would be impossible unless you use ajax for one of the scripts.

Comment: Look into `setTimeout`.

Comment: Search: Asynchronous JavaScript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parallel JavaScript Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897625/parallel-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1):

This will increase unit by 1 every three seconds and something by 25 every five seconds. The time units are in milliseconds so divide by 1000 to get the time in seconds and vice versa.

```
setInterval(function() { 
    unit++;
}, 3000);

setInterval(function() { 
    something += 25;
}, 5000);
```