# Function with return value of other function as variable, async or not?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var module = {}
module.setDate = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    return d;
}
```

Say I now have:

```
function logDate(){
   var date = module.setDate();
   console.log(date)
   console.log('finished')
}
```

Is the setting of `var date` to the return value of `module.setDate()` synchronous or asynchronous? Could the console ever look like:

```
undefined
'finished'
```

Comment: _"Could the console ever look like..."_ No, the code posted will always return synchronously.  But I feel like perhaps there's more to this question than you're asking?

Comment: The function call to `.setDate()` will be synchronous.

Comment: Not really tbh, I'm just wanting to use a slightly more complicated version of date setting like the above and was wondering if I could end up with an undefined date in `logDate()`. Thats what I was wanting to know for sure, thanks @Pointy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're confusing a function call with a constructor.

```
var d = new Date();
```

This will create a `Date` object immediately, that that's what your function is returning.

On the other hand, if your function were

```
var module = {}
module.setDate = function() {
    return function() {
        var d = new Date();
        return d;
    }
}
```

This would be asynchronous, but not parallelly executed.  The execution of the function you return would wait until you call the function.

```
function logDate(){
   var date = module.setDate();
   console.log(date() /* <--- need these parens, now! */)
   console.log('finished')
}
```

In order to truly execute in parallel, which I think it what you are trying to ask by saying "asynchronous", then I'd suggest reading up on one of these links.

- [Parallel JavaScript Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897625/parallel-javascript-code)
- http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/
- https://adambom.github.io/parallel.js/